# Capturing optional words in Ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

The following two lines of text might be encountered:

> John's new car
>   John's car

The modifier "new" is optional. I thought this would work:

```
([a-zA-Z'\s]+)\s?(new)?\s?(car)
```

According to Rubular, for the first case, this gives `["John's new", "", "car"]`. What I am looking for is this:

> John's new car

```
["John's", "new", "car"]
```

And in this case:

```
John's car

["John's", {}, "car"]
```

Comment: Is it possible to encounter other words/adjectives besides "new"? Colors, "old", "fast", "slow"? As is, all answers will fail if another word is encountered. Also, any answers that hardcode "red" will take maintenance over time to deal with each new variant.

Comment: Yes, other words could be encountered. But I would just use ([a-zA-Z'\s]+)\s?(new|old|fast|slow)?\s?(car)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z'\s]+?)\s?(new)?\s?(car)
             ^ added
```

You need to make the first subgroup non greedy, it's eating up the second subgroup match.

```
>> /([a-zA-Z'\s]+?)\s?(new)?\s?(car)/.match "John's new car"
=> #<MatchData "John's new car" 1:"John's" 2:"new" 3:"car">

>> /([a-zA-Z'\s]+?)\s?(new)?\s?(car)/.match "John's car"
=> #<MatchData "John's car" 1:"John's" 2:nil 3:"car">
```

Comment: Thanks! I like both your answer and Mark's below, but I guess I can only vote for one, and you were first. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `\s` from your character class if you want words to *not* include whitespace.

This works:

```
([a-zA-Z']+)\s?(new)?\s?(car)
```

[Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/kS9bYIYImp)

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, other words could be encountered. But I would just use ([a-zA-Z'\s]+)\s?(new|old|fast|slow)?\s?(car)

That is not good planning, because you could have a very large list of optional words and a continuing task of updating your source code.

A better solution would be to put optional words into a YAML file, load it at runtime, create a regex from it, and plug that into the pattern at the right place.

Why YAML format? It's easy to read for you, and easily loaded/parsed by multiple languages. You could use a text flatfile if you choose.

Why create a regex pattern instead of looping over the list? Because a regex will be much faster and just as accurate if it's done right.

Here's how I'd go about it:

Save this to a YAML file called 'test.yaml':

```
---
- red
- blue
- green
- yellow
- fast
- slow
- old
- new
```

Save this to 'test.rb':

This is how I fish:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'
require 'yaml'

adjectives = YAML.load_file('./test.yaml')
adjective_regex = /(?:\b#{ Regexp.union(adjectives).source }\b)/i
search_regex = /([a-z']+) \s+ (#{ adjective_regex }?) \s? (car)/ix

[
  "John's car",
  *adjectives.map{ |a| "John's #{ a } car" }
].each do |s|
  s[search_regex]

  pp [$1, $2.empty? ? {} : $2, $3]
end
```

Running that outputs:

```
["John's", {}, "car"]
["John's", "red", "car"]
["John's", "blue", "car"]
["John's", "green", "car"]
["John's", "yellow", "car"]
["John's", "fast", "car"]
["John's", "slow", "car"]
["John's", "old", "car"]
["John's", "new", "car"]
```

At this point, maintaining the application doesn't require modifying the code, instead, I modify the data.

Now, Perl has a module called [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aAssemble) that is very useful for this sort of use. It lets us take a list of words and generate a very efficient pattern for handling the search:

Instead of a regex looking like `"red|blue|green|yellow|fast|slow|old|new"`, it will look like:

```
(?-xism:(?:(?:(?:yel|s)lo|ne)w|(?:ol|re)d|green|blue|fast))
```

Here's the code that generated that pattern:

```
use Regexp::Assemble;

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
my @adjectives = qw[red blue green yellow fast slow old new];
foreach my $a (@adjectives) {
  $ra->add($a);
}

print $ra->re, "\n";
```

This sample doesn't create a shorter pattern, but the more words that get added, the more optimized the pattern gets. It's pretty amazing what it can generate. What's important about this is you can easily take the code to generate the list, and, use it to build a regex for Ruby's parser.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share this advice.